# Why do my cookies expire instantly?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a function that sets cookies; in this function I use PHP's `setcookie` function in order to set cookies, for example:

```
setcookie('auth', $token, time() + 3600);
```

The function I'm using `setcookie` in is as follows:

```
function SetAuthenticationCookie($id, $rememberme) {
    $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    executeNonUserQuery([db query]);
    if ($rememberme) {
        setcookie('auth', $token, time() + (86400 * 90));
        setcookie('profid', $id, time() + (86400 * 90));
    }
    else
    {
        setcookie('auth', $token, time() + 3600);
        setcookie('profid', $id, time() + 3600);
    }
}
```

The above cookie should be valid for one hour, and appears this way in the browser (see below screenshot).

In the browser the cookies show before it redirects (the page is dynamic), therefore the cookies *are* being set. However they disappear when the page redirects. This causes a problem because the main UI page (where the login page redirects) checks for the presence of the authentication cookies and redirects back to the login page if they don't exist.

[image]

I followed the [official documentation for `setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and am unable to see what the problem is. Chrome reports that the cookie path is `/internal` therefore it's a possibility that the actual page can't access them (the page path is `/pages`), but this still doesn't explain why they disappear completely from Chrome.

The cookie is set to expire in an hour after it is set, but this doesn't explain the disappearance of the cookies unless I'm missing something crucial in `setcookie` concerning the setting of the expiration time. I experience the same issue in other browsers, so it has to be something that I've done wrong or missed.

I confirm that I have nothing that unsets or expires the cookies (I haven't implemented that yet). I've tried setting the path to `/` but this doesn't fix the problem.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

*I'm aware of the security issues here, my priority is to fix this problem first.*

Comment: You must be using the `BrowniePoints 1.0` extension. They always run out before you can use them  :)

Comment: But seriously: We are not going to be able to help unless you show us some code that demonstrates this issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly I provided the code that I'm using, it should technically work fine, that's what's really confusing about this. I can provide the entire PHP function that I'm using `setcookie` in plus an execution plan if you want me to (don't want to put too much redundant code in the question)?

Comment: Sometimes clearing your browsers cache or cookies solved this kind of issues. No harm in trying :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, I tried setting the path to `/` again and that *did* work. I'm confused as to why it didn't work earlier but there you have it, apologies. PHP's timezone was also incorrect so I set it (was UTC, set it to the correct `Europe/Guernsey`), seems like the issue was a combination of the path and timezone.

Comment: Ok, I have undeleted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by two factors:

- The cookie path
- PHP's timezone

As mentioned in the question I had already tried setting the cookie path to `/` with no effect. However I did not consider PHP's timezone, which was set to UTC.

Setting the timezone to the correct `Europe/Guernsey` plus setting the cookie path to `/` (root) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, add a path and make it available to the whole website rather than just the folder the first script is in

```
setcookie('auth', $token, time() + 3600, '/');
```

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: Bang for boom ;-)